# blank spaces in dataframe

Tags: python, numpy

I need some help figuring out the best method for adding a blank space between each table from a Pandas data frame when converting to CSV inside a range-based for loop

```
# Read a PDF File
df = tabula.read_pdf("out.pdf", pages='all')
with open('out.csv', 'a') as f:
    for x in df:
        x.to_csv('out.csv', mode ='a', sep=',', index=False)
        f.write('\n')
```

The intended output would be as follows...

```
1,12,22,33,43,54,64,75,84,95
2,13,23,34,44,55,65,76,85,96
3,14,24,35,45,56,66,77,86,97
4,15,25,36,46,57,67,78,87,98
5,16,26,37,47,58,68,79,88,99
6,17,27,38,48,59,69,80,89,100
7,18,28,39,49,60,70,,90,
8,,29,,50,,71,,91,
9,19,30,40,51,61,72,81,92,101
10,20,31,41,52,62,73,82,93,102
11,21,32,42,53,63,74,83,94,103
1P,2P,3P,4P,5P,6P,7P,8P,9P,10P

104,115,124,135,144,155,165,176,186,197
105,116,125,136,145,156,166,177,187,198
106,117,126,137,146,157,167,178,188,199
107,118,127,138,147,158,168,179,189,200
108,119,128,139,148,159,169,180,190,201
109,120,129,140,149,160,170,181,191,202
110,,130,,150,161,171,182,192,203
111,,131,,151,,172,,193,
112,121,132,141,152,162,173,183,194,204
113,122,133,142,153,163,174,184,195,205
114,123,134,143,154,164,175,185,196,206
11P,12P,13P,14P,15P,16P,17P,18P,19P,20P
```

However, instead, two new line chars are appended to the end of the file.

I may have a fundamental misunderstanding as to how the append mode works for the to_csv function and would appreciate clarification on why the lines are being added to the end of the file, instead of inline where they are wanted.

A code-based alternative is also appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
OUTPUT_FILE = 'out.csv'
for i, x in enumerate(df):
    x.to_csv(
        OUTPUT_FILE,
        mode='w' if i == 0 else 'a',
        sep=',',
        index=False
    )
    if i < len(df) - 1:
        with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'a') as f:
            f.write('\n')
```

I suspect what might be happening in your example is that there are two buffers opened at the same time for the same file. `df.to_csv` writes to one, `f.write` to the other and at the end they get flushed to the disk consecutively (first the `df.to_csv` one and then the one with two new line characters).